# WPF MVVM UpdateSourceTrigger=Excplict

Tags: wpf, mvvm, undo, updatesourcetrigger

i've a contentcontrol in my Wpf-App (MVVM) which is bound to an object and displays the objects properties in textboxes, so the user can edit the values of the properties.
I want to implement undo/redo functionality with the command pattern of the GoF.
For this i need a point where i can create the command and set it into my undomanager.
My idea was to add a submitbutton. When the button is pressed, i update the sources of the textboxes (my properties) and create my command object to make the changes undoable (saving the old state of the object and the new state).
But:
- For using a submit button i need to set UpdateSourceTrigger of the textboxes to Explicit. If i want to update my sources i need to reference the controls in my view, which is bad as far as i've learned. How can i do that?
With MVVM i have to create a Command (WPF Command, not my undo redo command) for the SubmitButton but i don't see how to apply the changes to the properties from that command without referencing the textboxes (further hey are generated via datatemplates).

Thanks Walter

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `TextBox` controls are bound to the properties in the `ViewModel` class. If you bind your submit button to a `ViewModel Command` which in turn can add appropriate command to you `Command Pattern Collection` and also changes some of `ViewModel` properties, the values in the `Textbox` controls will also be updated. Now, for a `Textbox` to update it's value when the value of a property it is bound to changes, the `ViewModel` class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event from the property setter with that's property's name as an argument.

Comment: One more thing, to store the current state of the object from a command in the ViewModel class, you don't need references to the TextBox controls. You can directly access the properties from the ViewModel class itself because the View is in fact bound to the ViewModel.